# Using the "DVD Maker 2" (EM2980 chip) on Xenialpup

Tags: linux, drivers, video-capture, puppylinux

The not so well documented product "DVD Maker 2" from kworld I find only has an official driver for Windows.  The two possible solutions I could think of is acquiring a driver for linux, or somehow running the Windows driver on linux (I doubt that will work).

What I ask for is a solution to run this device on Xenialpup in order to convert a composite video signal + analog audio to thier respective digital input device, that may be a camera and line input, or something similar.

Details on the device:

- Package name: `DVD Maker 2 (kworld)`
- Board labels: `E162061  HU319 Rev:D`
- Chip: `eMPIA EM2980`

I have no experience with drivers and Linux, so all details are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have basically the same EM2980 board as well. My one has the ID 1b80:e600, with the Empia specific ID being 146.
Confusingly, the name found in the EEPROM is EM28286 yet the .inf file for the corresponding Windows driver says it's an EM28285.

Either way, it looks like the EM2980 differs from most other Empia chips in a fairly significant way: it seems that the [video decoder is integrated](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-media/msg73699.html) into the chip itself, rather than being a separate chip on the board. I don't know if the decoder is one of the [two products](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/media/usb/em28xx/em28xx.h#L430) that are currently supported by the em28xx driver for analogue capture devices, or if it's something different entirely.

Essentially, there doesn't seem to be any publicly available documentation for the EM2980, so all we have to go on are USB captures on Windows. This doesn't seem to be quite enough information to piece together a solid enough understanding. [As you can see here](https://pastebin.com/GUSfxmgK), there are a lot of register pokes that aren't recognised by the Linux em28xx driver's [list of known registers](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/media/usb/em28xx/em28xx-reg.h). This Empia card will take a bit more work to crack ;)

Side note: I wrote some tools to help with analysing the device, which you can find [here](https://github.com/jbendtsen/em28286/tree/master).

References:

https://linux-media.vger.kernel.narkive.com/2Oym3YXq/strange-empia-device#post11

https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-media/msg73699.html